# How do I get a distinct list of objects with JpaRepository.findAll using a Predicate?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have something like:

```
Predicate p = ...;
List<MyObject> objectList = (List<MyObject>) myRepository.findAll(p); // myRepository is autowired
```

This gets the list of all MyObjects, with duplicates. Is it possible to get a **DISTINCT** list instead?

Do I really need to use an EntityManager and CriteriaBuilder? Or can it be done with just the predicate and the repository object?

I'm not talking about iterating through the list manually and removing duplicates, or using any Collections API, but more on JPA or QueryDSL API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible.Below are the simple steps that I can think of

- Implement hashCode() and equals() in your MyObject Class.
- Create a Set based on your above list using its constructor directly which takes a Collection as an argument.

Comment: +1 That's certainly another approach, but not what I was expecting. Updated my question - not to consider using the Collections API. But I might consider this if all else fails.

Comment: @geffchang anyhow internally spring also would do the same :).

Comment: I can't use the Collections API, mainly because MyObjects is an autogenerated entity. It's generated by the convert DB table to JPA entities function in a JPA project in Eclipse. So, adding  an equals and hashCode might not be a good idea. I'd have to make another wrapper class for that, which is again not a good idea.

Comment: @geffchang you can always do that.Where is the problem?

Comment: There's no problem with using a wrapper class at all. Just checking if there are other ways, using JPA or QueryDSL API. If not, I'll just use the Collections API (with wrapper classes).